# How does android change the Bitmap's buffers dynamically

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I saw a code making images blurry and surprised at how bitmap dynamically changes its buffer when I used the `draw` function.

Let's say there is a `CustomeView` subclassed from `View` and It has `imageView` and `bitmap` as a property.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private View blurredView;
    private Bitmap bitmapToBlur;
```

When the `CustomView` is instantiated from the code, It passes an Image resource to `blurredView` to set the `blurredView` property:

```
//MainActivity
ImageView backgoundImage = findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
CustomView blurView = findViewById(R.id.blured_backroung_view);
blurView.setBlurredView(backgoundImage);
```

And then inside of `CustomView`'s `onDraw` function, clears the imageView by calling `eraseColor`

```
//onDraw function
this.bitmapToBlur.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

At this stage `bitmapToBlur` has a buffer cleared with `0`

[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGUcH.png)

But as soon as I execute next line:

```
this.blurredView.draw(this.blurCanvas);
```

`bitmapToBlur` changes its buffer value.

[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRAcN.png)

Clearly, `draw` will render `blurredView` not `CustomView`. And yet `bitmapToBlur` somehow reflects `blurredView`'s image. I don't see any connection between these two objects and got confused since the result comes out great.

Entire Code:

```
public class BlurView extends View {
    private int frostyFactor, blurredViewWidth, blurredViewHeight;
    private boolean downsampleFactorChanged;
    private View blurredView;
    private Bitmap bitmapToBlur, blurredBitmap;
    private Canvas blurCanvas;
    private RenderScript rs;
    private ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurRs;
    private Allocation inputImage, outputImage;


    public BlurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context c){
        this.initializeRenderScript(c);
        this.setBlurRadius(20);
        this.setFrostyFactor(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (this.blurredView != null) {
            if (this.prepare()) {
                if(this.blurredView.getBackground() != null && this.blurredView.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable){
                    this.bitmapToBlur.eraseColor(((ColorDrawable)this.blurredView.getBackground()).getColor());
                }else {
                    this.bitmapToBlur.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }

                this.blurredView.draw(this.blurCanvas);
                this.blur();
                canvas.scale(this.frostyFactor,this.frostyFactor);
                canvas.drawBitmap(this.blurredBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void blur() {
        this.inputImage.copyFrom(this.bitmapToBlur);
        this.blurRs.setInput(this.inputImage);
        this.blurRs.forEach(this.outputImage);
        this.outputImage.copyTo(this.blurredBitmap);
    }

    private boolean prepare() {
        int width = this.blurredView.getWidth();
        int height = this.blurredView.getHeight();

        if (this.blurCanvas == null
                || this.downsampleFactorChanged
                || this.blurredViewWidth != width
                || this.blurredViewHeight != height){
            this.downsampleFactorChanged = false;
            this.blurredViewWidth = width;
            this.blurredViewHeight = height;

            int scaledWidth = width / this.frostyFactor;
            int scaledHeight = height / this.frostyFactor;
            if (this.blurredBitmap == null){
                this.bitmapToBlur = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                if (this.bitmapToBlur == null){
                    return false;
                }
                this.blurredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledWidth,scaledHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                if(this.blurredBitmap == null){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            this.blurCanvas = new Canvas(this.bitmapToBlur);
            this.blurCanvas.scale(1.0f/(float)this.frostyFactor, 1.0f/(float)this.frostyFactor);
            this.inputImage = Allocation.createFromBitmap(this.rs, this.bitmapToBlur, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,1);
            this.outputImage = Allocation.createTyped(this.rs, this.inputImage.getType());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setBlurredView(View bv){
        this.blurredView = bv;
    }

    public void setBlurRadius(float r) {
        this.blurRs.setRadius(r);
    }

    public void setFrostyFactor(int f) {
        if (f <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Downsample factor must be greater than 0.");
        } else {
            if (this.frostyFactor != f) {
                this.frostyFactor = f;
                this.downsampleFactorChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setFrostyArtifactFactor(float f){
        this.frostyArtifactFactor = f;
    }

    private void initializeRenderScript(Context context) {
        this.rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        this.blurRs = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(this.rs, Element.U8_4(this.rs));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Clearly, `draw` will render `blurredView` not `CustomView`. And yet `bitmapToBlur` somehow reflects `blurredView`'s image" - `blurredView` and `CustomView` is the same view, you call `setBlurredView` passing the view declared in your xml to `CustomView`. So, `bitmapToBlur` is the bitmap placed in `R.id.backgroundImage`,  it makes sense that it would be affected..

Comment: `CustomeView` and `blurredView` are different views. When `blurredView` gets the chance to call `onDraw`, it will call its own not `CustomeView`'s. I just found that `blurredView` has `blurCanvas` to render and I guess `draw` will render the image on what this `blurCanvas` has which is `bitmapToBlur`. XP This code was hard to read..